# Is it possible to Connect to all databases/schemas at once via RMySQL?

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

In R, I am trying to connect to a particular host that currently has 3 schemas with an N number of tables each. I want to connect to all of the schemas at the same time, instead of cycling through each of them every time.

With the packages RMySQL, the usual way to connect to a particular database is the following:

```
 library(RMySQL)
 con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="dbhere", username = "userhere", password = "pwdhere", host="host.here")
```

This allows me to connect to one particular schema (via dbname) and do whatever I need with the tables there. I could write a for loop to cycle through the schemas each time, but every time a new schema is added it would have to be updated manually in R.

The following also do not work:

```
#here I changed paramets in dbname
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname=NULL, username = "userhere", password = "pwdhere", host="host.here")

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname=ALL, username = "userhere", password = "pwdhere", host="host.here")

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="ALL", username = "userhere", password = "pwdhere", host="host.here")

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname=all, username = "userhere", password = "pwdhere", host="host.here")

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname="all", username = "userhere", password = "pwdhere", host="host.here")
```

From the [RMySQL manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf), the argument dbname is described as 'string with the database name or NULL. If not NULL, the connection sets the
default daabase to this value.'